# Setting optimization settings in visual studio through cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

When I create a project for visual studio (2015) by using a cmake file, the optimization level is set to O2 by default in release mode.

I am unable to find a way to change this to other values within a cmake file.
Additionaly, I would also need a program database (.pdb) to be build.

I tried:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O0")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O0")
```

and

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O0")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O0")
```

as proposed here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187455/how-to-compile-without-optimizations-o0-using-cmake

without the success. Anybody knows the right way?

Comment: On Stack Overflow we tend to maintain question post and solution(s) **separated**. Instead of adding `SOLVED` clause, [you may post answer on your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). This feature is perfectly fit for your case: please, use it.

Comment: good to know that. Its fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this code:

```
string(REPLACE "-O2" "-O0" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
string(REPLACE "-O2" "-O0" CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` and friends did not work for me.
What did was:

```
target_compile_options(${target_name} PRIVATE "/Zi")   
target_compile_options(${target_name} PRIVATE "/Ob0")   
target_compile_options(${target_name} PRIVATE "/Od")   
target_compile_options(${target_name} PRIVATE "/RTC1")   

message(STATUS "updating options for target: ${target_name}")
```

It seems like cmake 3.x and up has it s.t. if we add a compile option that conflicts with a previous option, the newer option will take precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Following the Antonio's answer the solution for me was:

```
First change the optimization setting:
string(REPLACE "/O2" "/Od" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")

Than add a flag that creates program database file:
string(CONCAT CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}" " /Zi")
```

This also works but clears everything that was set to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE before the call.

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "/Od /Zi")
```

Answer (score 1):

For [Windows MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o-options-optimize-code?view=msvc-160), I'm using this flag: -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/Od".
Looks  like this:

```
cmake src\ -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/Od"
```